# Saving awk output to variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, centos

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

I'm trying to save the awk output into a variable.

```
variable = `ps -ef | grep "port 10 -" | grep -v "grep port 10 -"| awk '{printf "%s", $12}'`
printf "$variable"
```

EDIT: $12 corresponds to a parameter running on that process.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not really clear. What is the error you get?
What is the line from `ps -ef` and what do you expect in $variable ?
(if you can not provide real data, then generate a sanitized example that shows the problem instead.)

Comment: Problem:  variable does not show up in the printf statement.

End goal:  $12 corresponds to a serial number that is running with that process.  I want to save that parameter into a variable so I can work with it.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

variable=`ps -ef | grep "port 10 -" | grep -v "grep port 10 -" | awk '{printf $12}'`
echo $variable
```

Notice that there's no space after the equal sign.

You can also use `$()` which allows nesting and is readable.

Comment: thanks RUI & NiKiZe, it was the spacing before and after the equal sign.

Comment: @wens , how to save multiple variables, from a single command?

Answer (score 25):

I think the $() syntax is easier to read...

```
variable=$(ps -ef | grep "port 10 -" | grep -v "grep port 10 -"| awk '{printf "%s", $12}')
```

But the real issue is probably that `$12` should not be qouted with ""

Edited since the question was changed, This returns valid data, but it is not clear what the expected output of `ps -ef` is and what is expected in variable.

Comment: There's supposed to be an `awk` after the last pipe and before the `'{printf`. It was probably accidentally removed when the answer was edited.

Answer (score 3):

as noted earlier, setting bash variables does not allow whitespace between the variable name on the LHS, and the variable value on the RHS, of the '=' sign.

awk can do everything and avoid the "awk"ward extra 'grep'. The use of awk's printf is to not add an unnecessary "\n" in the string which would give perl-ish matcher programs conniptions. The variable/parameter expansion for your case in bash doesn't have that issue, so either of these work:

```
variable=$(ps -ef | awk '/port 10 \-/ {print $12}')

variable=`ps -ef | awk '/port 10 \-/ {print $12}'`
```

The '-' int the awk record matching pattern removes the need to remove awk itself from the search results.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable=$(ps -ef | awk '/[p]ort 10/ {print $12}')
```

The `[p]` is a neat trick to remove the search from showing from `ps`

@Jeremy
If you post the output of `ps -ef | grep "port 10"`, and what you need from the line, it would be more easy to help you getting correct syntax